# Send iOS Actionable Push Notification via MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

Is it possible to send an actionable push notification to an iOS device via MS Graph API?

I am specifically looking to redirect the end user to a URL. The OS version compliance notifications have a '*How to resolve this*' action built in to them that redirects to [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204).